# How to JOIN two collection by _id with where condition in Mongodb and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've two collections called user and subscription, every subscription has user_id which is _id of user collection. How can I join these two collections by where condition with is_account_active = 1.

Please check the below code which I'm using:

```
const users = await User.find({ is_account_active: 1 });
```

This will get me all users which have is_account_active flag as 1 but at the same time, I want subscription details also with respective user ids.

Answer (score 1):

You can below query.

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      your_condition
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subscriptions', // secondary db
      localField: '_id',
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'subscription' // output to be stored
    }
  }
]);
```

But instead of using **_id** as a foreign it should be better if you can use a new
field like **user_id** in primary collection and can use auto increment on that which will now automatically insert new data with new unique id, and you can create index on it for faster query execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example `aggregate` function.
If you keep user_id as string and you have mongo db version >= 4.0 then you can make `_id` conversion to string (because _id is an ObjectId type):

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      is_account_active: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subscriptions',     //collection name
      localField: '_id',
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'subscription'.        //alias
    }
  }
]);
```

But it is a better idea to store user_id in Subscription schema as Object id

```
user_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
}
```

so then

```
const users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      is_account_active: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subscriptions',     //collection name
      localField: '_id',
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'subscription'.        //alias
    }
  }
]);
```

[More about ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

[More about Aggregate function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)

Comment: It is returning an empty array

Comment: Do you keep user_id as ObjectId or string? Maybe you should post some data from User and Subscriptions collections that you want to get, can't really help without some info. @KunalDholiya

Comment: Yes, it is string

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mongodb right now with Mathon's excellent answer.  I don't have the reputation points to state this in the comments:  I believe there is a stray period after the 'as' and the argument foreignKey should be foreignField - at least Mongodd 6.0.3 is presenting an error with it and NodeJS. It works for me with those changes as shown below.

```html
const users = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      is_account_active: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": {
        "$toString": "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'subscriptions',     //collection name
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'user_id',
      as: 'subscription'        //alias
    }
  }
]);
```